# replace string to string Gulp replace

Tags: gulp

I tried this code to replace foo by bar  in my test.txt

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var replace = require('gulp-replace-task');

gulp.task('default', function () {
gulp.src('test.txt')
.pipe(replace(
      'foo',
      'bar'
    ));

});
```

the content of my test.txt is

```
hello foo
```

and the text still the same

Comment: So... did it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using gulp-replace-task instead of gulp-replace. They work quite a bit differently. You'll need to install gulp-replace and change your replace var to:

```
var replace = require('gulp-replace');
```

You'll also need to add:

```
.pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
```

as soyuka suggested

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the destination, here `gulp.dest('.')`.

If you don't write the file, it'll only change in-memory, and so won't show up in the result.

Comment: even when I add  .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));   it didn't work